# How to query different type of documents in parallel?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm using Cosmos DB (DocumentDB) and .NET Core. Let's say I have to completely different documents (simplified example):

```
public class Market // DocumentType = "market"
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}

public class City // DocumentTyupe = "city"
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

To get all of those I can run two queries one by one:

```
var markets = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Market>()
.Where(x => x.DocumentType == "market").ToList()

var cities = client.CreateDocumentQuery<City>()
.Where(x => x.DocumentType == "city").ToList()
```

What is the recommended approach to execute both queries in parallel? So I'm thinking something like this:

```
var markets = QueryMarkets(); // returns Task    
var cities = QueryCities(); // returns Task
Task.WhenAll(markets, cities); //execute in parallel
```

**Is there something built into that I could benefit from?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built in functionality with Cosmos that would allow you to execute multiple queries in parallel from the server side. Your approach to awaiting them in parallel using `Task.WhenAll` in your client application is the correct one.

The only other alternative would be to create a custom Stored Procedure that could aggregate the results of more than one query but based on the example that you're showing I don't think there would be any benefits for either speed or RU consumption to go down that route.